# how to delete blitted images for a nnew animation like jump or dying

Tags: python, pygame

Above says it all. When the character **jumps**, I want the **walkRight** and **walkLeft** images to go away when I jump. As of now, they stay and the jump animation is just looping over the left and right walk animations. Here is the code:

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('cropped_run/walk1.png'), pygame.image.load('cropped_run/walk2.png'), pygame.image.load('cropped_run/walk3.png'), pygame.image.load('cropped_run/walk4.png'), pygame.image.load('cropped_run/walk5.png'), pygame.image.load('cropped_run/walk6.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.transform.flip(walkRight[0], True, False), pygame.transform.flip(walkRight[1], True, False),  pygame.transform.flip(walkRight[2], True, False),  pygame.transform.flip(walkRight[3], True, False),  pygame.transform.flip(walkRight[4], True, False),  pygame.transform.flip(walkRight[5], True, False),]

def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if not (self.standing):

            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//5], (self.x - 20,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        #Stays facing in direction when key is released
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x,self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x - 20,self.y))

        #JUMP ANIMATION RENDER
        if self.isJump:
            if self.jumpCount >= -8:
                win.blit(jumpUp[self.jumpCount//4], (self.x,self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(jumpDown[self.jumpCount//4], (self.x,self.y))

        if self.isJump and self.left:
            if self.jumpCount >= -8:
                win.blit(jumpUp_L[self.jumpCount//4], (self.x - 20,self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(jumpDown_L[self.jumpCount//4], (self.x - 20,self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 8, self.y+20, 26, 40)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the walking image only `if not self.isJump:`:

```py
def draw(self, win):
    # [...]

    if not self.isJump:

        if not (self.standing):

            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//5], (self.x - 20,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        #Stays facing in direction when key is released
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x,self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x - 20,self.y))
```